# How to print menu again

Tags: java

How to return my menu selection with the code i have below?
After the program gives the output, how can i go back to the menu again?

```
import java.util.*;
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Meme {
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Scanner inp= new Scanner(System.in);
        int choose;
        System.out.println("Enter your selection:\n1 for Addition\n2 for substraction \n3 for Multiplication\n4 for division");

        choose = inp.nextInt();

        int num1,num2;
        int ans;
        System.out.println("Enter first number:");
        num1 = inp.nextInt();
        System.out.println("Enter second number:");
        num2 = inp.nextInt();


        switch (choose){
        case 1:
            System.out.println(add( num1,num2));
            break;
        case 2:
            System.out.println(sub( num1,num2));
            break;      
        case 3:
            System.out.println(mult( num1,num2));
            break;
        case 4:
            System.out.println(div( num1,num2));
            break;
            default:
                System.out.println("Illigal Operation");


        }



    }
    public static int add(int x, int y)
    {
        int result = x + y;
        return result;

    }
    public static int sub(int x, int y)
    {
        int result = x-y;
        return result;
    }
    public static int mult(int x, int y)
    {
        int result = x*y;
        return result;
    }
    public static int div(int x, int y)
    {
        int result = x/y;
        return result;
    }

}
```

After the program gives the output, how can i go back to the menu again?

Comment: Add a `while(true)` loop and have an exiting condition in your menu.

Comment: whre exactly? Like in the code?

Answer (score 3):

Have a while loop wrapping the menu and switch statement. Add an exiting condition to the menu, where if the user enters a specific value then return.

Something on the lines of this (I am assuming any other input from user as an exit signal, you can change it as per your needs):

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner inp = new Scanner(System.in);
    int choose;

    while (true) {
        System.out.println(
                "Enter your selection:\n1 for Addition\n2 for substraction \n3 for Multiplication\n4 for division\nExit: Any other input");

        choose = inp.nextInt();

        int num1, num2;
        int ans;
        System.out.println("Enter first number:");
        num1 = inp.nextInt();
        System.out.println("Enter second number:");
        num2 = inp.nextInt();

        switch (choose) {
        case 1:
            System.out.println(add(num1, num2));
            break;
        case 2:
            System.out.println(sub(num1, num2));
            break;
        case 3:
            System.out.println(mult(num1, num2));
            break;
        case 4:
            System.out.println(div(num1, num2));
            break;
        default:
            return;

        }
    }
}
```